# Parent <-> Child relation ownership problem

Tags: rust

I'm just starting to learn Rust and I'm having some troubles understanding how ownership works in my case:

```rust
use std::ops::IndexMut;

// ================================================

struct Container {
    root: Option<ContainerItem>,
    items: Vec<ContainerItem>
}

impl Container {
    pub fn create_item(&mut self) -> usize {
        let item = create_test_item();
        let idx = self.items.len();
        self.items.push(item);
        return idx;
    }
    
    pub fn get_item(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut ContainerItem {
        return self.items.index_mut(index);
    }

    pub fn new() -> Container {
        let mut x = Container {
            root: None,
            items: Vec::new()
        };
        
        x.root = Some(create_test_item());
        
        return x;
    }
}

// ================================================

struct ContainerItem {
    idx: usize,
    children: Vec<usize>,
    parent: usize,
    has_parent: bool
}

impl ContainerItem {
    pub fn add_child(&mut self, value: &mut ContainerItem) {
        value.parent = self.idx;
        value.has_parent = true;
        self.children.push(value.idx);
    }
}

// ================================================

fn create_test_item() -> ContainerItem {
    ContainerItem {
        idx: 1,
        children: Vec::new(),
        parent: 0,
        has_parent: false
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container::new();
    
    let item_index = container.create_item();
    let item = container.get_item(item_index);
    
    if let Some(mut root) = container.root {
        root.add_child(item);
    }
}
```

I have a `Container`, with `ContainerItem`s. Each `ContainerItem` can have children and also has a reference to its parent (both children and the parent are stored as their index in `Container`'s `items` vec). This is all fine, adding items to the container works, but when I try to add a child to `Container`'s root item (which is a `ContainerItem`), it throws errors:

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `container.root` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:68:12
   |
66 |     let item = container.get_item(item_index);
   |                --------- borrow of `container` occurs here
67 |     
68 |     if let Some(mut root) = container.root {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of borrowed `container`
69 |         root.add_child(item);
   |                        ---- borrow later used here

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `container.root.0` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:68:17
   |
66 |     let item = container.get_item(item_index);
   |                --------- borrow of `container` occurs here
67 |     
68 |     if let Some(mut root) = container.root {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ move out of `container.root.0` occurs here
69 |         root.add_child(item);
   |                        ---- borrow later used here
```

If I change the call to `add_child` to use for e.g. `create_test_item()` as the argument, then it works fine.

I assume this might be because `Container`'s `items` field has ownership over all `ContainerItem`s? But I'm passing it by reference to `add_child` so I think this shouldn't matter, since I'm not changing the owner?

Comment: this is one of the things which can not be implemented in (safe) rust; You might try to apply ugly hacks like storing  the items somewhere externally and addressing them by a numeric index.  But it would be probably better to give up the object oriented approach and implement it in another way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trouble comes from the fact that in this Parent ←→ Child relation the items are sometimes referred to with references and sometimes with indices.
So, it is not always clear when the borrow should concern the container as a whole or just one item which is a part of it.

Moreover, the root item is not stored in the same place as the other items so no index can be used to refer to it.

I reorganised your code in order to always rely on indices (as far I understand your intention; maybe it is not always equivalent to what you wanted initially).
This way, as soon we have to adjust many indices, we just borrow the container as a whole.
Consequently, the `add_child()` method is moved from the item implementation to the container.

Note that the `has_parent` boolean was also a good opportunity to switch to `Option`.

Note also that, as long as we borrow an item with `get_item()` or `get_item_mut()`, we cannot create new items because the reallocation inside the `Vec` could invalidate the references; the borrow-checker will forbid that.

```rust
pub struct Container {
    root: Option<usize>, // why not implicitly alway 0?
    items: Vec<ContainerItem>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn create_item(&mut self) -> usize {
        let idx = self.items.len();
        let item = create_test_item(idx);
        self.items.push(item);
        idx
    }

    pub fn get_item(
        &self,
        index: usize,
    ) -> &ContainerItem {
        &self.items[index]
    }

    pub fn get_item_mut(
        &mut self,
        index: usize,
    ) -> &mut ContainerItem {
        &mut self.items[index]
    }

    pub fn new() -> Container {
        let mut this = Container {
            root: None,
            items: Vec::new(),
        };
        this.root = Some(this.create_item());
        this
    }

    pub fn add_child(
        &mut self,
        parent_idx: usize,
        child_idx: usize,
    ) {
        // forget child in previous parent if any
        if let Some(prev_parent_idx) = self.items[child_idx].parent {
            let prev_children = &mut self.items[prev_parent_idx].children;
            let idx = prev_children.iter().position(|i| *i == child_idx);
            prev_children.remove(idx.unwrap());
        }
        // give the child its new parent
        let child = &mut self.items[child_idx];
        child.parent = Some(parent_idx);
        // append this new child to the parent
        let parent = &mut self.items[parent_idx];
        parent.children.push(child_idx);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ContainerItem {
    idx: usize,
    children: Vec<usize>,
    parent: Option<usize>,
}

fn create_test_item(idx: usize) -> ContainerItem {
    ContainerItem {
        idx,
        children: Vec::new(),
        parent: None,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container::new();
    let item_idx = container.create_item();
    println!("item: {:?}", container.get_item(item_idx));

    if let Some(root_idx) = container.root {
        println!("root: {:?}", container.get_item(root_idx));
        println!("~~~~~~~~");
        container.add_child(root_idx, item_idx);
        println!("item: {:?}", container.get_item(item_idx));
        println!("root: {:?}", container.get_item(root_idx));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   let item = container.get_item(item_index);

   if let Some(mut root) = container.root {
        root.add_child(item);
    }
```

`container.get_item` has already borrowed a value from `&self`. Therefore `root.add_child` will be restricted as long as that borrow exists.

Since the goal is simply to add an element to vec, there is no need to even have the attribute root: `Option<ContainerItem>`. By default when a new container is created, items can be an empty vector and when there is an item to be added it can be pushed to the vector.

Here is a simple way to implement the parent-child relationship

```
struct Parent<'a> {
    children: &'a mut Vec<Child>,
}

impl Parent<'_> {
    pub fn add(&mut self, c: Child) -> () {
        let root = &mut self.children;
        root.push(c)
    }
    
    pub fn get_item(
        &self,
        index: usize,
    ) -> &Child {
        &self.children[index]
    }
}

struct Child {
    i: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let c1 = Child { i: 1 };
    let mut data = vec![c1];
    let c12 = Child { i: 1 };
    data.push(c12);
    let mut p = Parent { children: &mut data };
    let c12 = Child { i: 2 };
    p.add(c12);
    let item = p.get_item(2);
    println!("{}", item.i) //2
```

Obviously other traits can be added to the parent